# Balancer is not moving data to new shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I tried MongoDB horizontal sharding using 3 shards initially and I saw data were divided equally between the shards. I have used "hashed" for the shard key.

Now I have added the 4th shard to this existing setup. But I can see balancer is not moving chunks to the 4th shard so I inserted more than 1millions documents but still data chunks are moving to the 4th shard i.e 4th shard is empty.

Please find the commands that I have executed

**Config Servers**

```
mongod --configsvr --port 27019 --replSet rs0 --dbpath data1 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --configsvr --port 27020 --replSet rs0 --dbpath data2 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --configsvr --port 27021 --replSet rs0 --dbpath data3 --bind_ip localhost


mongod --configsvr --replSet rs0 --dbpath data1 --bind_ip localhost


rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "rs0",
    configsvr: true,
    members: [
      { _id : 0, host : "localhost:27019" },
      { _id : 1, host : "localhost:27020" },
      { _id : 2, host : "localhost:27021" }
    ]
  }
)
```

**Three shards**

```
mongod --shardsvr --port 37019 --replSet rp1  --dbpath data1 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 37020 --replSet rp1  --dbpath data2 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 37021 --replSet rp1  --dbpath data3 --bind_ip localhost
rs.initiate( { _id : "rp1",  members: [   { _id: 0, host: "localhost:37019" },   { _id: 1, host: "localhost:37020" },   { _id: 2, host: "localhost:37021" } ] })

mongod --shardsvr --port 47019 --replSet rp2  --dbpath data1 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 47020 --replSet rp2  --dbpath data2 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 47021 --replSet rp2  --dbpath data3 --bind_ip localhost
rs.initiate( { _id : "rp2",  members: [   { _id: 0, host: "localhost:47019" },   { _id: 1, host: "localhost:47020" },   { _id: 2, host: "localhost:47021" } ] })

mongod --shardsvr --port 57019 --replSet rp3  --dbpath data1 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 57020 --replSet rp3  --dbpath data2 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 57021 --replSet rp3  --dbpath data3 --bind_ip localhost
rs.initiate( { _id : "rp3",  members: [   { _id: 0, host: "localhost:57019" },   { _id: 1, host: "localhost:57020" },   { _id: 2, host: "localhost:57021" } ] })
```

**Enabling sharding**

```
mongos --port 40000 --configdb rs0/localhost:27019,localhost:27020,localhost:27021

mongo --port 40000
sh.addShard( "rp1/localhost:37019,localhost:37020,localhost:37021");
sh.addShard( "rp2/localhost:47019,localhost:47020,localhost:47021");
sh.addShard( "rp3/localhost:57019,localhost:57020,localhost:57021");


sh.enableSharding("demodb");

sh.shardCollection("demodb.collection", { timeStamp : "hashed" } )
```

Now I ran the script to insert data into demodb.collection and I can able to see the data spread across above three shards.

**So I added 4th shard using below command**

```
mongod --shardsvr --port 57119 --replSet rp4  --dbpath data1 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 57120 --replSet rp4  --dbpath data2 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --shardsvr --port 57121 --replSet rp4  --dbpath data3 --bind_ip localhost
rs.initiate( { _id : "rp4",  members: [   { _id: 0, host: "localhost:57119" },   { _id: 1, host: "localhost:57120" },   { _id: 2, host: "localhost:57121" } ] })

mongo --port 40000
sh.addShard( "rp4/localhost:57119,localhost:57120,localhost:57121");
```

Now I added few more data into demodb.collection thinking that balancer will move the chunks to 4th shard to balance data among all 4 shards. But it didn't worked.

**Below the output of Shard status**

```
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("6052f2e74f97982edd469896")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "rp1",  "host" : "rp1/localhost:37019,localhost:37020,localhost:37021",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "rp2",  "host" : "rp2/localhost:47019,localhost:47020,localhost:47021",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "rp3",  "host" : "rp3/localhost:57019,localhost:57020,localhost:57021",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "rp4",  "host" : "rp4/localhost:57119,localhost:57120,localhost:57121",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "4.2.7" : 1
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                rp1 256
                                rp2 256
                                rp3 256
                                rp4 256
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
        {  "_id" : "demodb",  "primary" : "rp2",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("0034d13f-d46f-4248-9bec-021b8949336b"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                demodb.collection
                        shard key: { "timeStamp" : "hashed" }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                rp1 2
                                rp2 2
                                rp3 2
                        { "timeStamp" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "timeStamp" : NumberLong("-6148914691236517204") } on : rp1 Timestamp(1, 0)
                        { "timeStamp" : NumberLong("-6148914691236517204") } -->> { "timeStamp" : NumberLong("-3074457345618258602") } on : rp1 Timestamp(1, 1)
                        { "timeStamp" : NumberLong("-3074457345618258602") } -->> { "timeStamp" : NumberLong(0) } on : rp2 Timestamp(1, 2)
                        { "timeStamp" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "timeStamp" : NumberLong("3074457345618258602") } on : rp2 Timestamp(1, 3)
                        { "timeStamp" : NumberLong("3074457345618258602") } -->> { "timeStamp" : NumberLong("6148914691236517204") } on : rp3 Timestamp(1, 4)
                        { "timeStamp" : NumberLong("6148914691236517204") } -->> { "timeStamp" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rp3 Timestamp(1, 5)
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB sharded collection not rebalancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908686/mongodb-sharded-collection-not-rebalancing)

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575643/mongodb-sharding-how-does-it-rebalance-when-adding-new-nodes you don't have enough chunks.

Comment: Thank you all. Let me go through the above links.